# Как парсить ссылку на Ютубе

Tags: python, парсер

Есть код, он парсит ютуб (без api). Хочу парсить канал и вкладку О КАНАЛЕ, там в адресной строке добавляется /about. Но так как каналов хочу спарсить пачку(парсю трансляции, и канал каждой трансляции), то почему-то через раз работает. Очень часто пишет:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Сейчас он выводит, но когда их много - то из 200 почти 100 не выводит.

Какой есть другой метод получить ссылку? Когда Вы смотрите видео, то название канала, оно кликабельно. Вот я и парсю это название канала (ссылку) и добавляю +/about и тогда открывается квладка О КАНАЛЕ  и там парсю страну, но ругается что nontype object has no atribute "get". Как по другому можно получить ссылку?

Comment: может вы парсите 200 каналов без задержки и ютуб вас игнорит как спам атаку ?

Comment: я думаю капчу кидает

Comment: поставил слип на 10 секунд и работает, спасибо!